# What is the Gaussian Integral for negative $n$ exponents?

Tags: gaussian-integral

If I have a Gaussian integral of the form $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-2}e^{-ax^2}dx, a>0$$ do I use the expression $$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n}e^{-ax^2} dx=\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^{k+1}a^k}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}},~~n=2k, k\in\mathbb Z, a>0$$
or is there another expression to be used for negative exponents? I am asking because this is the formula that I know, but when I evaluate the integral using Wolfram Alpha, it tells me that the integral does not converge, whereas, with the formula above, I get some finite value.

Thanks.

Comment: $x=0$ is a problem because it's a non-removable discontinuity

Comment: So essentially the formula does not apply?

Comment: Your expression is valid only for $n>0$.  Regardless, $$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{e^{- a x^2}}{x^2}\ dx$$ does not converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I(\epsilon)=\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-a x^2}}{x^2}\,dx=\frac{e^{-a \epsilon ^2}}{\epsilon }-\sqrt{\pi a} \,
   \text{erfc}\left(\epsilon\sqrt{a}  \right)$$ I suppose that you see what happens to the first term when $\epsilon \to 0$.